# How to show Image from String Url in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path,
          filename: "test.${image.path.split(".").last}")
    });

    var dio = Dio();
    var res = await dio.post(
      "$url/users/profile/image/add",
      data: formData),
    );
```

Code above returns like this below

```
{success: true, profile_picture: /files/images/users/40.png}
```

Which packages do i have to use when I want to upload '/files/images/users/40.png'

Comment: what does the file upload have anything to do with `"How to show Image from String Url in flutter?"`? you want to upload or download? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink I want to download image from String url from server

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For downloading an image from URL, use [image_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader) package like this :

```
try {
  // Saved with this method.
  var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ko2ic/image_downloader/images/flutter.png");
  if (imageId == null) {
    return;
  }

  // Below is a method of obtaining saved image information.
  var fileName = await ImageDownloader.findName(imageId);
  var path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId);
  var size = await ImageDownloader.findByteSize(imageId);
  var mimeType = await ImageDownloader.findMimeType(imageId);
} on PlatformException catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
```

For uploading an image to server use below code:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Upload(File imageFile) async {    
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
      var length = await imageFile.length();

      var uri = Uri.parse(uploadURL);

     var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
          filename: basename(imageFile.path));
          //contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'));

      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      var response = await request.send();
      print(response.statusCode);
      response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
        print(value);
      });
    }
```

[You can also refer to this tutorial for learning image upload in Flutter.](https://medium.com/@nitishk72/flutter-uploading-image-to-server-aec76876b9e1)

For showing an image from server URL use this code :

```
Image.network(
  imageUrl,
)
```

Here imageUrl can be any image URL like

https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png

Answer (score 0):

To show an an image from the internet using its URL, you can do this :

```
Image.network(
  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
)
```

To learn more, [click here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image).